# CDI @Transactional with Self Invocation

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly-8, transactional

**Environment :**

JAVA EE 7

CDI 1.2

WildFly 8.2.0

**Code :**

I have a JAVA class having following method.

```
@SessionScoped
@Named("orgBean")
public class OrgBean{

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething(){

        //EM.persist();
        //call private method 
        innerMethod();

    }

    private void innerMethod(){


        EM.persist(); //why is this working ?

    }

}
```

1)The method doSomething() runs inside a transaction. This method calls another private method innerMethod().

2)The innerMethod() uses EM.persist() call.

**Issue/Query :**

1)How is EM.persist() working ?

2)I am trying to relate this to Spring framework. Since CDI uses proxies (method invocation OrgBean.doSomething will be through PROXY) and innerMethod is self invocation , how EM.persist() call will work since innerMethod() won't be running inside transaction ?

3)Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in `innerMethod()` runs inside the transaction started by the call to `doSomething()`, and ending when the `doSomething()` method returns.

1. transactional proxy's `doSomething()` method is called
2. proxy starts a transaction
3. proxy calls the OrgBean's actual `doSomething()` method
4. OrgBeans's `doSomething()` does whatever it wants, including calling other methods. The proxy doesn't care, and can't even know about it
5. OrgBeans's `doSomething()` method returns to proxy's doSomething() method wrapper
6. transactional proxy commits the transaction.

In pseudo-code, the proxy basically does the following:

```
public void doSomething() {
    startTransaction();
    try {
        orgBean.doSomething();
        commitTransaction();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        rollbackTransaction();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

It's a bit more complex than that in reality, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This means CDI proxy mechanism is different under the hood than Spring

Comment: If this were an `@EJB` non-proxied self invocation would miss things like method interceptors and new TX boundaries (vi `@TransactionAttribute`). I believe the same is the case for CDI as well which would be something to watch out for if so.